# Locate similar entries in mySql

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I was trying to locate duplicate entries in my sql table which I achieved it quite easily with the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM sds_bank_phrases INNER JOIN (Select bank_statement FROM sds_bank_phrases GROUP  BY bank_statement HAVING COUNT(bank_statement) > 1) dup ON sds_bank_phrases.bank_statement = dup.bank_statement;
```

- Now what I am trying to look for is the entries which have same data but a full stop additionally added.
- For example have bank_id 1 with bank_statement Yes
- bank_id 2 with bank_statement Yes.
- bank_id 3 with Yes, It has been edited.
- so from the above example I just want to extract 1st two entries because they are the close once. just full stop is the difference.
- I have a 20000 bank_statements and how do I extract such entries?

**DB table**

[image]

- In the above image we can see the data Not known has duplicate entries.
- The query posted can find all the entries with id 1274, 1353,1418,2455,3026 but cannot find 5637.
- Because there is a full stop in that entry. Which is not considered to be duplicate.
- Expected result would be to pull in the Not known as well.
- It should ignore the ban_statement with id with 2787 because the bank_statement is different.

Comment: update you question with a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I have added them @scaisEdge

Comment: EXplain better  you want count as duplicate also the row with the full stop (dot) at  the end ?

Comment: Yep that is what I mean

Comment: JUst for ending  dot .. not others chars?

Comment: no just for ending dots... not other characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a  TRIM(TRAILING ‘.’ FROM your_column);

```
SELECT * 
FROM sds_bank_phrases 
INNER JOIN (Select TRIM( TRAILING '.' FROM bank_statement ) as clean_bank_statement
FROM sds_bank_phrases GROUP  BY bank_statement HAVING COUNT(TRIM( TRAILING '.' FROM bank_statement )) > 1) dup 
    ON TRIM( TRAILING '.' FROM sds_bank_phrases.bank_statement ) = dup.clean_bank_statement;
```

Comment: No I am getting an unexpected TEXT_STRING if i am using the  TRIM( TRAILINF '.' FROM bank_statement )

Comment: Yes  .. TRAILING    ... typo error  .. answer  updated .